# Problema con suma con valor "NaN en JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

primero que todo gracias por leerme. Les comento...Estoy haciendo una especie de calculadora con javascript. Tengo dos cuadros, el primero en donde ingreso los datos (cuadro "datos" y el segundo es a donde llegan los cálculos ya realizados (cuadro "situación actual") por medio de un botón.

La idea es que sume la suscripción base + el valor de la nube + la suscripción variable. Esta ultima se obtiene de (N° de portafolios totales - N° de portafolios en suscripción base ) * precio por portafolio adicional.

Al realizar los cálculos me da el error "NaN" en la suscripción variable y el TOTAL y no he podido solucionarlo, desde ya agradezco sus aportes, muchas gracias.

```js
var NPT=Number(document.getElementById('NPT').value); 
var NPSB=Number(document.getElementById('NPSB').value);
var PPA=Number(document.getElementById('PPA').value); 
var SB=Number(document.getElementById('SB').value); 
var SB1=Number(document.getElementById('SB1').value); 
var NUBE=Number(document.getElementById('NUBE').value); 
var SV=Number(document.getElementById("SV").value); 


function Data() {

var resultado = (NPT-NPSB) * PPA ;
var resultado2 = resultado + SB1 + NUBE;

document.getElementById("TOTALSA").value=resultado2;
document.getElementById("SB").value=document.getElementById('SB1').value;
document.getElementById("NUBE").value = document.getElementById('VAN').value;
document.getElementById("SV").value =resultado;
}
```

```html
<body>

  <div class="card float-right" style="width: 32rem;">
    <div class="card-header"><h5>Situación actual</h5></div>
    <div class="card-block p-0">
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
    <table class="table table-hover">

  <tbody>
      <tr>
          <th class="text-center" scope="row">Suscripción base </th>
          <td class="trans text-center"> <input id="SB" class="form-control"></td>
          
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th class="text-center" scope="row">Suscripción variable</th>
        <td class="trans text-center"> <input id="SV" class="form-control"> </td>
        
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <th class="text-center" scope="row">Nube</th>
        <td class="trans text-center"><input id="NUBE" class="form-control"></td>
        
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <th class="text-center" scope="row">TOTAL</th>
        <td class="trans text-center"><input id="TOTALSA" class="form-control"></td>
        
      </tr>
    
  </tbody>
</table>
</div>
</div>
            <div class="card-footer text-muted"><h6></h6></div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="card mt-3" style="width: 36rem;">
<div class="card-header"><h5>Datos</h5></div>
<div class="card-block p-0">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-12">

      <div class="container">
    <form>

      <div class="row mt-2">

        <div class="col">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="inputCity" class="font-weight-bold">N° Portafolios totales</label>
              <input  type="number" class="form-control" placeholder="Escribe el valor" id="NPT">
            </div>

          </div>


      
        <div class="col">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputCity" class="font-weight-bold">N° Portafolios en suscripción base</label>
            <input type="number" placeholder="Escribe el valor"  class="form-control" id="NPSB">
          </div>

        </div>

      </div>

    </form>

      <form>
          <div class="row">

            <div class="col">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="inputCity" class="font-weight-bold">Suscripción base</label>
                    <input id="SB1"  placeholder="Escribe el valor" class="form-control" >
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>


          <div class="col">
              <div class="form-group">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="inputCity" class="font-weight-bold">Precio por portafolio adicional</label>
                  <input id="PPA"  placeholder="Escribe el valor" class="form-control" >
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

          </div>
            </form>


            <form>
              <div class="row">

                <div class="col">
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="inputCity" class="font-weight-bold">Valor almacenamiento en la nube</label>
                        <input id="VAN" placeholder="Escribe el valor" class="form-control" >
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>


              <div class="col">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="form-group">
                    
                    
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>

              </div>
                </form>
                <div class="trans text-center">
                  <button onclick="Data()" type="button" class="btn btn-primary  mb-3 font-weight-bold" >Realizar Comparación</button>
              </div>
          </div>
  </div>
</div>
    <div class="card-footer text-muted"><h6></h6></div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Mientras editaba tu código vi que `Document` está con mayúscula y debe ser minúscula `document`. Revisa si ya funciona.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la aclaración, efectivamente ya no sale el error de "NaN", pero sigue sin hacer los cálculos, tanto el total como la suscripción variable me las deja en "0"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Los valores de los input deben leerse dentro la función.

```
function Data() {
    
    var NPT=Number(document.getElementById('NPT').value); 
    var NPSB=Number(document.getElementById('NPSB').value);
    var PPA=Number(document.getElementById('PPA').value); 
    var SB=Number(document.getElementById('SB').value); 
    var SB1=Number(document.getElementById('SB1').value); 
    var NUBE=Number(document.getElementById('NUBE').value); 
    var SV=Number(document.getElementById("SV").value); 
    
    var resultado = (NPT-NPSB) * PPA ;
    var resultado2 = resultado + SB1 + NUBE;
    
    document.getElementById("TOTALSA").value=resultado2;
    document.getElementById("SB").value=document.getElementById('SB1').value;
    document.getElementById("NUBE").value = document.getElementById('VAN').value;
    document.getElementById("SV").value =resultado;
    }
```

Comment: Eso era, muchas gracias por tú tiempo, puros errores de novato, pero me servirá para no equivocarme más en eso jajaja en serio muchas gracias!!.